# Intellij does not recognize spring boot entities in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, spring-boot, yaml

I am building a few spring boot applications using intellij 2016 ultimate edition, and I cannot configure it to recognize my entities in the JPQL queries.

The applications work fine and compile without any problems.

I added the JPA facet, and also tied to play with the JPA provider in the project settings, but to no use.

I am using `yml` files for configurations, and I don't have any XML configurations.

I am also using `gradle` as my build system.

Here is my `application.yml` file:

```
logging:
    file: app.log
    path: /var/log

spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:~/app
    username: ***
    password: ***
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

If there are other files that could help, please say in the comments, and I will add them.

Comment: Did you inject the correct language/reference in your JPQL query strings?

Comment: maybe Intellij expects a persistence.xml and Spring's bastardisation of the JPA standard is getting in the way?

Comment: I've created multiple Spring boot applications with JPA so far in IntelliJ, it's unlikely that that is true. Are you sure your entities are in a subpackage of your main class?

Comment: @g00glen00b if you mean by sub packages that my main class in under 'com.test', and my entities are under 'com.test.*', than yes I'm sure

Comment: @NeilStockton maybe, but I'm not using a persistence.xml, and I don't want to change my code for my IDE

Comment: @AliDehghani I don't understand what you mean, but the code does work when I run my applications